# Multiple link errors building Qt 5.15 application for Android

Tags: android, c++, clang, linker-errors, qt5.15

Application builds fine with **Qt 5.12.9** for Android. However fails with **5.15.1** on linking phase (compiles fine as deprecated Qt API was fixed). Building for `arm64-v8a` ABI only:

```
qmake ANDROID_ABIS="arm64-v8a" ...
```

Have multiple link errors like this:

```
~/Qt/5.15.1/android/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs_impl.h:415: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
obj/QGCMapEngine.o: In function `QList<QString>::append(QString const&)':
~/Qt/5.15.1/android/include/QtCore/qlist.h:626: undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
~/Qt/5.15.1/android/include/QtCore/qlist.h:628: undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
~/Qt/5.15.1/android/include/QtCore/qlist.h:629: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
~/Qt/5.15.1/android/include/QtCore/qlist.h:644: undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
~/Qt/5.15.1/android/include/QtCore/qlist.h:646: undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
~/Qt/5.15.1/android/include/QtCore/qlist.h:647: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
```

Tried to fix `AndroidManifest.xml` like mentioned here: [Qt for Android known issues](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Android_known_issues) with no luck. Reproducible with latest Qt SDK installed and with Qt built from sources in docker. Any ideas what the problem is and how to fix?

#### References:

- Full list of errors: [qgroundcontrol#9136 (comment)](https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol/pull/9136#issuecomment-714802202)
- Project: [qgroundcontrol](https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol), branch: [android_build_fix_qt5.15](https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol/pull/9136)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `-nostdlib++` hack fix in the following line: [QGCCommon.pri#L60](https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol/blob/master/QGCCommon.pri#L60)

```
QMAKE_LINK += -nostdlib++ # Hack fix
```

For **5.15** need to remove it and patch `AndroidManifest.xml` to correctly build APK. This line could be removed for **5.12** as well as it [was **ndk20** problem](https://forum.qt.io/topic/103713/error-cannot-find-lc-qt-5-12-android) while currently Qt Creator installs and uses **ndk21** by default.